# Trying to get toggle buttons in Twitter Bootstrap web page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons on a twitter bootstrap page in the same position, and I am trying to toggle them by showing one and hiding one...

I used

```
$("button1").hide()
$("button2").show()
```

or vice versa

```
$("button2").hide()
$("button1").show()
```

This kind of works, but the formatting gets disrupted, the buttons loose padding.. and I can't figure out how to code this...

Comment: You've got a number of syntax errors--you're not closing either 'style' tag, you're not closing your button tags (should be <button /> instead of <button>), and your JavaScript is missing semi-colons. The unclosed style tags in particular seem like they could be responsible.

Comment: SidCool, I see you just removed the HTML... is this a good idea if there's a chance the unclosed style tags there were causing the problem?

Comment: a jsfiddle might be helpful to check your exact code and help you to solve your problem (i doubt your jQuery code is exactly what you indicated ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `margin 0;` since the second button have some margin initially.

from tucker:

```
<div class="span6">
    <button id="button1" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary"  style="color: white;" name="open" type="button" >open</button>    
    <button id="button2" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary"  style="color: white; display:none; margin:0;"  name="open" type="button" >close</button>
    </div>
```

js

```
$("#button1, #button2").click(function(){
$("#button1").toggle();
 $("#button2").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/xAV7e/3/

Answer (score 1):

html

```
 <div class="span6">
    <button id="button1" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary"  style="color: white;" name="open" type="button" >open</button>    
    <button id="button2" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary"  style="color: white; display: none;"  name="open" type="button" >close</button>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#button1, #button2").click(function(){
$("#button1").toggle();
 $("#button2").toggle();
});
```